# 2D member array - initialize with zero.

Tags: multidimensional-array, member

I am trying to initialize an "2D member array" with zeros. I dont wan't do loop over the whole array in the constructor to initialize it with zero. So my approach is the following, but I get a an warning C4351: new behavior: elements of array 'A::array' will be default initialized ...

```
int const row = 5;
int const col = 5;


class A{
    private 
        int array[row][col] = {};
};
```

Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

See this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287601%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

```
int[,] n4 = new int[3, 2] { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }, { 5, 6 } };
```

However if you do not know the size, you can't use an array. Or rather, you would need to pick a size, and if you ended up needing more then you would have to allocate a new, larger, array, copy the data from the old one into the new one, and continue on as before (until you exceed the size of the new one...)

If you do not know the sizes, generally you would go with one of the collection classes - ArrayList, List<>, LinkedList<>, etc.

Comment: The size is just row x col, so Im rather confused. I mean if I initalize with zero in the constructor, is this the common practice?

Comment: Yes it is common practice. Another good link for you to get started is the following http://www.dotnetperls.com/2d-array.